# app under development in xcode does not run on device without internet

Tags: iphone, xcode, wifi

as this is my first app i don't know if this is how its supposed to be by apple but when transferring the app on the device and then disconnect the usb connecting the device and relaunching the app it it does not run unless the device is connected to the wifi.. is this a problem or is this the way it supposed to be? is this going to affect the app when it will be launched on the app store? thank you in advance.. ps. the app does not need wifi connection to work but it has some features that need it, like maps and push notifications..

Comment: Which app is it please elaborate.... Also if the app is using bits and pieces of parsing data then the app will run anywayz , it shouldnt until and unless the first view of the app is depending on the net...

Comment: is a tabbat app. the first view is a tab with a textView and an image on top. i do have a default.png as a splash screen and if i'm not connected on the internet it stops/ "freezes?" on the splash screen. but if i am connected it goes on and loads the entire app with no problems at all..

Answer (score 0):

mmm, if you use maps... you need an internet connection, wifi or phone connection, and you should just to test via code if you are connected before use it, but your app should work in other controllers...

anyway, try to find out if in yourApp-info.plist file there's the setting:

"Application uses Wi-Fi"

if so, try to remove it

Comment: there is no such setting like that in my plist.. its a tabbar app and the first view its just a textView and an image. i do though have implemented in the app-delegate the push notifications. i do not know if this affects my problem in any way..

Answer (score 0):

for push notification you must be sending your device token to the server using web services. please add network check for web service calls using Reachability classes.

Comment: can you give me some sample code? i just followed the tutorial on parse for notifications..